# Блокировка при чтении Socket.getInputStream()

Tags: java, android, веб-сервер

**Цель:** реализовать простейший веб-сервер.

**Препятствие:** блокировка во время чтения входного потока.

**Описание действий проверки программы:** при проверке на устройстве, на котором запущен сервер, всё работает так, как ожидалось: *в браузере выводится мой запрос на сервер*.
Если же проверять с какого-либо другого устройства, находящегося в локальной сети, то поведение меняется: ***иногда** браузер показывает, что загружает данные, но этот процесс не заканчивается*. Чаще всего (в Chrome) загрузка сопровождается надписями `Подключение...` или `Ожидание 192.168.0.118:1024...` внизу страницы, но так бывает не всегда.

**Результаты диагностики и попытки исправления:** опытным путём я определил, что блокировка происходит на `reader.readLine()`, чему нашёл теоретическое обоснование.
Я пробовал игнорировать запросы, в которых `input.available() < 1` или `!reader.ready()`, - иногда работало так, как ожидалось, иногда - браузер сообщал о том, что соединение сброшено, что довольно логично.

**Вопросы:**

1. Блокировка происходит из-за того, что `BufferedReader` будет продолжать читать ввод, пока он не достигнет конца, а конец - это закрытие сокета. Но как же тогда отправить браузеру ответ?
   ИЛИ см. пункт 2.
2. Каким способом можно предвосхитить блокировку?

---

**Приложение**

1. Ответственный за взаимодействие `Service`:

```java
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket();
server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));

while (isWorking) {
    Socket client = server.accept();

    final InputStream input = client.getInputStream();
    final OutputStream output = client.getOutputStream();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

    String line = "";
    StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.isEmpty()) break;
        responseBuilder.append(line);
    }

    String response = responseBuilder.toString();
    output.write(response.getBytes());
    output.flush();
    output.close();
}
```

2. Возможно, "этот вопрос связан проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится", и его следует удалить.

---

## UPD

В ходе выполнения экспериментов я установил, что работоспособность сервера зависит от данных браузера.  
Так как для всех запросов мой сервер возвращал строку с запросом, то и для запроса иконки `favicon.ico` браузер получал свой запрос.  
Я обнаружил, что, получая такой ответ, браузер запрашивает картинку ещё раз, далее следует череда запросов без запроса иконки, а потом - "бесконечная" обработка запроса (при некоторых неточных обстоятельствах обработка заняла 2 минуты и 21 секунду).  
Добавив строку:

```
if (line.contains(".ico")) code = 404;

//Обработка значения кода и создание ответа по всем правилам
ouput.write(response.getBytes());
output.flush();
output.close();
```

Я стал замечать, что браузер запрашивает картинку только первый запрос, получая сообщение о её несуществовании. Теперь все запросы выполняются достаточно быстро.
**НО** в настоящее время я не могу обработать запрос от браузера в режиме *инкогнито*. Однако в этом режиме запроса иконки нет...

#### Предварительный ответ:

проблема связана с работой браузера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно не получается воспроизвести проблему с текущим приложением. метод `readLine` по своей сути ожидает символа переноса строки и далее идет проверка на пустую строку, что означает завершение чтения метода запроса и его заголовков. Так или иначе преамбула (пустая строка) перед телом запроса (даже если его нет) должна быть.

Но логично, что второй запрос не может обработаться, пока не завершится первый, т.к. приложение у вас однопоточное.

Самое простое решение исключения блокировки - это вынести обработку ввода/вывода
данных сокета в отдельный поток, т.е.:

```
while (true) {
    final Socket client = server.accept();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final InputStream input = client.getInputStream();
                final OutputStream output = client.getOutputStream();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                String line = "";
                StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.isEmpty()) break;
                    responseBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }

                responseBuilder.insert(0, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");

                String response = responseBuilder.toString();

                output.write(response.getBytes());
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Кст если у вас есть зависания, то в данном случае еще нужно добавлять таймауты на открытые сокеты, чтобы так или иначе они закрылись и завершили поток.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Действительно, если открыть страницу сайта в соседней вкладке, то она так же будет "висеть". Но посмотрите на это с другой стороны - Вы пользователь, хотите перейти на другую страницу сайта, а она по какой-то причине не хочет загружаться... Конечно, потоки сделают доступным многопользовательский режим, но не решат проблему отдельно взятого соединения... Я считаю, что иметь `input.available() == 0` так часто, как получается это у меня, не очень нормально. Возможно, символы переноса строки теряются по дороге от ноутбука до телефона :D

Comment: @Вася Воронцов тайм-ауты - это решение проблем с «повисшими сокетами». А на самом деле если это не исследовательская работа, то не надо изобретать велосипед)) Лучше возьмите готовый веб-сервер

Comment: Конечно, готовый веб-сервер - альтернативное решение проблемы с "повисшими" сокетами, но оно в некоторой степени расходится с моей целью (первая строка вопроса). Так что велосипед - это то, что мне нужно. Надеюсь, мне удастся найти причину неожиданного поведения, и только если ошибка вызвана тем, до чего нельзя дотянуться, можно будет официально забить на эту фичу и, скажем, начать ограничивать время соединения

Comment: Вася Воронцов если тебе от запроса нужна первая строка, то советую читать посимвольно и далее сравнивать с чем-то (т.е. постепенно набираешь массив символов). Но так или иначе соединение клиента может оборваться в любой момент и сравнение опять повиснет

Comment: Не найдя способов ещё больше исправить неожиданное поведение, я сделал так, как вы посоветовали - начал создавать отдельный поток. И это сработало, теперь всё работает, не знаю, что это за магия, но, так, видимо, работает ОС. Спасибо

Comment: @Вася Воронцов ну только не забудьте, что за потоками надо следить, т.к. возможно некоторые могут спокойно навсегда повиснуть

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно буду их контролировать